# How do you find roots for a trig function with a range that contains the negative part of the unit circle?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I need to find all the solution sin the interval $-180 < x < 180$ for the equation
$$\tan x = \sqrt3 - 4$$

$$x = -66.21$$
$$180 - 66.21 = 113.8$$

Now this is my reasoning:

1. $-66.21$ is in the interval, but on the circle the quadrant it falls in is positive for all trig functions, so $-66.21$ is an invalid root.
2. The other root should be $-180 + 66.21 = -113.8 $ because the second quadrant is negative for tan.

Can anyone explain exactly why these reasonings are incorrect?

P.S.: I'm working in degrees, and the correct roots are $-66.21, 113.8$.

Comment: In your circle example, $-66.21^0$ falls in 4th quadrant where $x$ is positive but $y$ is negative i.e $\cos$ function is positive but $\sin$ is negative. So $\tan$ is negative so it is a valid answer.

Comment: please check in which quadrants, you have opposite signs for $\sin$ and $\cos$ - they are $2nd$ and $4th$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that

$$\tan x = \sqrt3 - 4<0$$

therefore $x$ lies on the $2^{nd}$ or the $4^{th}$ quadrant and since

$$\tan (-66.21°) =\tan (180-66.21°)= \sqrt3 - 4$$

those are there correct solutions.